# dnsmasq and dhcp-helper coexist problems

Tags: dhcp, dnsmasq

We run dhcp-helper and dnsmasq at same time in my device which have 
multiple bridges. (for example, br0 get ip address from DNSMASQ, and br1 get ip 
from another dhcp server through dhcp relay.)

The following are the steps I operate:

1. active dnsmasq on br0
2. active dhcp-helper with -p option on br1 for alternative port 1067/1068
3. add iptables rule to redirect dhcp request from br1:
   iptables -I PREROUTING -t nat -i br1 -p udp --src 0.0.0.0 --dport 67 -j DNAT --to 0.0.0.0:1067

After that, It seems like that the dhcp request successfully redirect to relay server on port 1067 (I can capture the requests in iptables INPUT chain), but I can not capture the dhcp requests from relay server using wireshark.

What else can I do? How can I let dhcp-helper and dnsmasq coexist in my device?

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved.
The DHCP Relay work well in latest version DNSMASQ 2.67.